# How to rest 2 formulas on netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I have two different formulas on netsuite that work. I'm tring to rest them, but there's always an error.

I'm working on a saved search with criteria
type= sales order
main line = False

The first check in a field on the items have a certain brand, if it does them bring the discount.
case when {item.csegccs_marcas} = 'KARLUZ' OR  {item.csegccs_marcas} = 'JONI' THEN {custcol_ccs_importe_con_descuento} ELSE 0 END

The Second one check the maximium value on a field and in case is 25% or 30% bring a fixed value.

CASE      WHEN MAX({custcol_ccs_porc_descuento_}) = '25%' THEN '3000000'      WHEN MAX({custcol_ccs_porc_descuento_}) = '30%' THEN '6000000'     ELSE '0'  END

I want to rest Formula 1 - formula 2.

I'm trying to rest the formulas, but I keep getting an error. I expect to get a result or if not a rest a comperison in which says if the formula 1 value is equal or higher than the second formula.